# Check if all nodes in graph are in distance of <=k from each other

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

In a given graph, I need to check, if all nodes in graph, are in distance of <=k from each other.

I Wrote a solution (simple C#) that runs with a loop on every node, and then checks that he has a k-distance to all the other nodes, but the time complexity is V * (V + E).
There is a more efficient way?

Code :

```
// node defenition
public class GraphNode
{
   public GraphNode(int data, List<GraphNode> neighbours)
   {
        Data = data;
       Neighbours = neighbours;
   }
}

// Loop on every Node, and find all k-distance neighbours
public bool IfAllGraphNodesInKdistance1(List<GraphNode> nodes, int k)
{
    for(int i=1; i< nodes.Count; i++)
    {
         if(FindKdistanceNeighboursInGraph(nodes[i], k).Count != nodes.Count)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}


// Find k-distance neighbours of a Node
public HashSet<GraphNode> FindKdistanceNeighboursInGraph(GraphNode node, int distance )
{

    HashSet<GraphNode> resultHash = new HashSet<GraphNode>();

    if (node != null && distance > 0)
    {
        HashSet<GraphNode> visited = new HashSet<GraphNode>();
        Queue<GraphNode> queue1 = new Queue<GraphNode>();
        Queue<GraphNode> queue2 = new Queue<GraphNode>();
        queue1.Enqueue(node);
        visited.Add(node);
        int currentDistance = 0;
        while (queue1.Count > 0 && currentDistance < distance)
        {
            GraphNode current = queue1.Dequeue();
            foreach (GraphNode graphNode in current.Neighbours)
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(graphNode))
                {
                    queue2.Enqueue(graphNode);
                    visited.Add(graphNode);
                    resultHash.Add(graphNode);
                }
            }
            if (queue1.Count == 0)
            {
                queue1 = queue2;
                queue2 = new Queue<GraphNode>();
                currentDistance++;
            }
        }
    }
    resultHash.Add(node); // if it will include current
    return resultHash;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a matrix from your graph, and then find the lower value in that matrix, it is also useful when you try to find the shorter way between nodes or apply some algorithm to your graph, etc.

[Simple example of representing a graph as matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eay54.png)

Comment: What do you mean by find the lower value?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you try to find the k-distance, not the lowest value. Instead of finding the lowest value you can find your distance in the matrix and then just get the coordinate and it will be a point and way which you try to find.

Comment: I think you are assuming that there is given a distance matrix, but it's not. Computing such a matrix is not free.

Comment: Also, OP is not looking for a node with k-distance from some other nodes. The OP wants an answer yes/no whether all nodes are not further than k from each other.

Comment: I'm talking about a matrix of distance. Yea, you are right computing isn't free but calculating of a matrix will be faster in the worst situation asymptotic complexity will O(n^2 - n) and for directed graph O((n^2 - n) / 2), and you also can optimize it(it depends on the concrete task). About the second comment, what OP wants to know it depends only on your definite task(it's your decision how to handle an array), I'm only assuming that handling will be faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot compute distance matrix in O(n^2). You have to run shortest path algorithm such as Floyd-Warshall, which is slower. In O(n^2) you can only do transformation from adjacency lists (neighbours lists) to adjacency matrix. But the adjacency matrix stores only direct connections between nodes, not shortest path distances between arbitrary nodes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your algorithm is actually V * (V + E).

I'm not sure if you can get any better in practice. You could definitely improve your code.

There are algorithms for computing all-pairs shortest paths, e.g., Floyd-Warshall. The fastest one for your case (undirected unweighted graph) is called Seidel's algorithm.